# How to give microsecond time base through timer in STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

Here is my code snippet:

```c
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

    static uint64_t count =0;
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, timer_out_Pin);
    count++;
    if(count == 1000000)
    {

        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(led_GPIO_Port, led_Pin);
        count=0;
    }
}



/* USER CODE END 4 */
```

I want to generate an interrupt every microsecond and in that I'm incrementing `count` variable. when the `count` inside timer callback function becomes 1 second I want to toggle an LED. But the LED is toggling every 10 seconds approximately instead of 1 second. Timer clock frequency=32 MHZ Prescalar value=31 and period=0.

Comment: Try `count == 1000000/10` as the  interrupt every microsecond is more like  interrupt every 
 10 microseconds.  Post code that shows how code sets up the interrupt.

Comment: The short answer to "I want to generate interrupt every microsecond" is "most likely, you do not".
If you need to toggle a LED every second, why run a microsecond timer? In software? If you need great precision, it starts with hardware (32 MHz is not 32.000000 MHz). Hard to answer without knowing what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: You real-time specification doesn't make sense and talking about microsecond accuracy without mentioning where you get your system clock from doesn't make sense either. _Why_ do you need an interrupt every microsecond and if so why did you pick some generic STM32?

Comment: ***`details or clarity`*** it is very clear what is wrong. Reopen it as the close reason makes no sense

Comment: @0___________ It is unclear what the goal is. This approach to blinking a LED once per second does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Execution of Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) [lasts more than 32 clock cycles](http://efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g15.html) - in your case, obviously, around 320 cycles.

ISR Entry and exit alone takes 12+12 cycles. Using Cube/HAL and not using compiler optimizations to their full extent easily increase this number to a few hundreds as in this case.

An extremely well written ISR executing the above code may take perhaps around 50-60 cycles, so even that wouldn't suffice for 32MHz clock. Even if this would be a higher-end STM32 with >100MHz system clock (where FLASH latency would slow down execution further, and/or introduce jitter) it is unreasonable to spend most execution time in such an interrupt.

Explore other methods to do what you want. Stick to using hardware to do microsecond precision operations (e.g. use a timer channel in output compare mode, a.k.a. PWM or One-pulse). If you need some event to be timed within microseconds in software, start a dedicated timer event for that, of the required duration (and don't expect it to be precise).